# Terraform state mv for_each module

Tags: terraform, rename

As part of a refactoring we're doing to our infrastructure, I'm trying to create a new hierarchy of modules and resources, and as part of it we are extracting some common infrastructure between modules.
I have a module (let's name it `worker`) currently at the `main.tf` file from which I start, which is a module with multiple instance (using a `for_each`):

```
module "worker" {
    for_each = local.workers
    source = "../base_service"
}
```

And now as part of the refactor, we want to create a base module which contains a lot of shared infrastructure:

```
module "worker" {
    source   = "../base_worker"
}
module "base_worker" {
    for_each = local.workers
    source = "../base_service"
}
```

This is simplified of course, but basically my module has been moved from `module.worker[*]` to `module.worker.module.base_worker[*]`

What I'm trying to do is rename the entire module all at once. I tried to find any built-in way in Terraform to do this but couldn't, and so I end up having to do `terraform state mv 'module.worker["worker_name"]' 'module.worker.module.base_worker["worker_name"]'` for each worker name in my locals.

When I try to run `terraform state mv 'module.worker' 'module.worker.module.base_worker'` I get a `No source address` error, and when I try to run `terraform state mv 'module.worker[*]' 'module.worker.module.base_worker'` I get a `Splat expressions (.*) may not be used here`

Comment: So you already moved everything, one by one?

Comment: For one module yes, but I have multiple modules and would prefer to have a better, uniform and single command to move all for each module

Comment: Have you looked at new block [moved](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/refactoring#moved-block-syntax)?

Comment: No, and while it may work (I haven't checked) it just causes a lot of extra redundant code when all I want is to simply rename a module, it's simply like renaming a variable

Comment: I'm afraid such thing as "simple" does not exist. Moved is the newest feature offered by TF.

Comment: @Marcin comment about `moved` block is definitely the path forward here. You could also do a find-and-replace on the state, but that would need to be a very careful plan inspection afterward.

Comment: Find and replace would cause the resources to be destroyed and recreated. I'm interested in simply renaming (moving) the states of the modules after a change in the hierarchy

Comment: It might help if you can show the _entire_ error message you got when you tried each of the commands you mentioned; currently your question is a mixture of incomplete code examples and incomplete output, which makes it hard to infer exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

I just did some refactoring of configuration into a module, and I think I saved some effort by first making this script `tf-bulk-move.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail

tfdir=$1
sed_expr=$2

cd $tfdir
while read line; do
  terraform state mv $line $(echo "$line" | sed -e "$sed_expr")
done < "statelist.txt"
```

Then in the module dir I ran

```
$ terraform state list > statelist.txt
```

And I took out lines for addresses that I didn't want changed. Then I did `chmod +x` on the script and ran it (this just prepends "module.env." to a bunch of addresses):

```
$ ./tf-bulk-move.sh ../env/dev "s/^/module.env./"
```

Comment: This indeed works, but I was looking for a built-in way to do so in terraform without creating external scripts (which I did for this, BTW). But thanks!

Comment: This is gold. Always coming back here when I am to lazy throwing these bash-lines together